# merging, grouping and sorting many xmls using xsl

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, merge

I am trying to merge multiple XML files (many hundreds) into one xml file but sorting and grouping them together by the tag `<accountno>` (also adding an extra container and a source filename tag).  I had tried doing this with C# but after researching it seems XSLT may be the easiest way to do it?  The problem is I am not sufficiently experienced in XSLT to achieve this.

I will try and demonstrate with three simplified XML files:

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OrigResponse>
     <address>
        <name1>Title1001257027</name1>
        <add1>address 1</add1>      
     </address>
<trans>
    <header>
        <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
    </header>
    <body>
       <accountno>123456789</accountno>
    </body>
</trans>
</OrigResponse>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OrigResponse>
  <address>
    <name1>Title1001257028</name1>
    <add1>address 1</add1>      
  </address>
<trans>
    <header>
      <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
    </header>
    <body>
        <accountno>000456700</accountno>
    </body>
</trans>
</OrigResponse>
```

File3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OrigResponse>
  <address>
    <name1>Title1001257027</name1>
    <add1>address 1</add1>      
  </address>
<trans>
    <header>
      <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
    </header>
    <body>
        <accountno>123456789</accountno>
    </body>
</trans>
</OrigResponse>
```

Because File1 and file3.xml are for the same account number these need to be merged into a unique container, while file 2 is in its own container. So for the output xml file I am looking at creating something like this:

merged.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>          
<OrigResponse>                                   
    <mergeinvoice>                                 
      <inputfile id="{cntr}">file3.xml</inputfile> 
      <address>                                  
          <name1>Title100125777</name1>           
            <add1>address 1</add1>                     
        </address>                                 
    <trans>                                      
        <header>                                   
            <h1text>mixed text</h1text>              
        </header>                                  
        <body>                                     
            <accountno>000456700</accountno>         
      </body>                                    
    </trans>                                     
    <inputfile id="{cntr}">file1.xml</inputfile> 
      <address>                                  
          <name1>Title1001257027</name1>           
            <add1>address 1</add1>                     
        </address>                                 
    <trans>                                      
        <header>                                   
            <h1text>mixed text</h1text>              
        </header>                                  
        <body>                                     
            <accountno>123456789</accountno>         
      </body>                                    
    </trans>                                     
  </mergeinvoice>                                
    <mergeinvoice>                                 
      <inputfile id="{cntr}">file2.xml</inputfile> 
      <address>                                  
          <name1>Title1001257027</name1>            
            <add1>address 1</add1>                     
        </address>                                 
    <trans>                                      
        <header>                                   
            <h1text>mixed text</h1text>              
        </header>                                  
        <body>                                     
            <accountno>123456789</accountno>         
      </body>                                    
    </trans>                                     
</OrigResponse>
```

So we have like-numbered (multiple and single) account numbers grouped together in the container `<mergeinvoice>.`

I also need the `<inputfilename>` tag inserted at the parent level containing the name of the source xml file for each account, and finally, an 'id' attribute in the same tag containing an incremented counter for each file (which I have shown with the variable placeholder `{cntr}`).

Is this something that can be achieved with XSLT as easily as suggested?  I realise this is a big ask, but if so, I'm hoping an expert can give me a steer in the right direction?

Many thanks in anticipation

Andy

Comment: What XSLT processor do you use? (Saxon, I hope).

Comment: Hi Mathias - Yes, I use SAXON

Comment: The reason I am asking is that `collection()` is only available with an XSLT 2.0 processor. Interesting question by the way, I'll look at it later if I find time.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I did read that Saxon supported XSLT 2.0 and basic support for parts of XSLT 3.0.  Really appreciate it if you manage to have a look

Comment: Martin has given you a very promising solution already. You need a version of Saxon that can process 2.0 stylesheets, preferably 9.5 (or 9.6, but 9.5 still seems more stable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0 the following stylesheet expects to be called with the initial template `main` (`it:main` command line option) and reads in all `*.xml` documents in the directory and groups them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <OrigResponse>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="collection('.?*.xml')/OrigResponse" group-by="trans/body/accountno">
      <mergeinvoice>
        <xsl:variable name="group-pos" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
          <xsl:with-param name="group-pos" select="$group-pos"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </mergeinvoice>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </OrigResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrigResponse">
  <xsl:param name="group-pos" as="xs:integer"/>
  <inputfile id="f{$group-pos}-{position()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()]"/>
  </inputfile>
  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output for your three sample files is

```
<OrigResponse>
   <mergeinvoice>
      <inputfile id="f1-1">file1.xml</inputfile>
      <address>
         <name1>Title1001257027</name1>
         <add1>address 1</add1>
      </address>
      <trans>
         <header>
            <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
         </header>
         <body>
            <accountno>123456789</accountno>
         </body>
      </trans>
      <inputfile id="f1-2">file3.xml</inputfile>
      <address>
         <name1>Title1001257027</name1>
         <add1>address 1</add1>
      </address>
      <trans>
         <header>
            <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
         </header>
         <body>
            <accountno>123456789</accountno>
         </body>
      </trans>
   </mergeinvoice>
   <mergeinvoice>
      <inputfile id="f2-1">file2.xml</inputfile>
      <address>
         <name1>Title1001257028</name1>
         <add1>address 1</add1>
      </address>
      <trans>
         <header>
            <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
         </header>
         <body>
            <accountno>000456700</accountno>
         </body>
      </trans>
   </mergeinvoice>
</OrigResponse>
```

So instead of a sequential counter for the id in form of `1`, `2`, and so on I have chosen an `id` value in the name `f[group-count]-[count-in-group]`. To achieve a sequential counter, it might be necessary to group first into a variable to have a temporary tree and then to push that through templates using `xsl:number` to count the `inputfile` elements, as in the following sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <OrigResponse>
    <xsl:variable name="temp-doc">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="collection('.?*.xml')/OrigResponse" group-by="trans/body/accountno">
        <mergeinvoice>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="group"/>
        </mergeinvoice>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$temp-doc/node()"/>
  </OrigResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrigResponse" mode="group">
  <inputfile>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()]"/>
  </inputfile>
  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inputfile">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output then is

```
<OrigResponse>
  <mergeinvoice>
     <inputfile id="1">file1.xml</inputfile>
     <address>
        <name1>Title1001257027</name1>
        <add1>address 1</add1>
     </address>
     <trans>
        <header>
           <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
        </header>
        <body>
           <accountno>123456789</accountno>
        </body>
     </trans>
     <inputfile id="2">file3.xml</inputfile>
     <address>
        <name1>Title1001257027</name1>
        <add1>address 1</add1>
     </address>
     <trans>
        <header>
           <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
        </header>
        <body>
           <accountno>123456789</accountno>
        </body>
     </trans>
  </mergeinvoice>
  <mergeinvoice>
     <inputfile id="3">file2.xml</inputfile>
     <address>
        <name1>Title1001257028</name1>
        <add1>address 1</add1>
     </address>
     <trans>
        <header>
           <h1text>mixed text</h1text>
        </header>
        <body>
           <accountno>000456700</accountno>
        </body>
     </trans>
  </mergeinvoice>
</OrigResponse>
```

Comment: Hi Mathias and Martin, the provided solutions worked fantastically well!  Thank you both for your input, it has certainly prompted me to make more use of XSLT in the future.  Regards.   Andy

Comment: @osirisja, as the answer solved your problem it is common practice to accept it so that is is marked as solved.